# How do I extract the text from this HTML tag?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

trying to build a web scraper in python to extract the dates from an HTML tag. I've [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGdPf.png) what the tag looks like, I'm trying to specifically extract the date. I'm able to isolate the tag itself, using: `dates = {item.find('span', {'class': 'POSITIVE'})}` and this retrieves me the whole tag.

To only get the text, I'm trying to use something along the lines of:
`dates = {item.find('span', {'class': 'POSITIVE'}).text}`

However when I do I get a traceback saying: "AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no text". I've used .get_text() and this doesn't work either, giving a similar traceback. How do I change my code to get the date text? I'm new to coding so I'm sorry if this is a basic problem.

Comment: In the first example, did you print the contents of `dates` to see that it actually found something?

Comment: Post a text as a text, not as an image. And post a [mre] and debugging details. What is your framework? Anyway the error message clearly says what's wrong. The ```item.find()``` returned the ```None```.